# Using Calculated Fields in ArcGIS Pro Reports

Tags: arcgis-pro, reports

I have built out a report in ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1 that displays fields from one attribute table. This was a report that I had built out in ArcMap, but we are working on moving everything over to Pro. The issue I am having is that in ArcMap you were able to perform calculations directly on the report utilizing fields. 
Ex: =field1/field2
In Pro I have not been able to find a way to do this, so I have had to write a python script to add the field to the table, calculate the field, run the report, and finally delete the field from the table. This is painfully slow compared to running the report in ArcMap. I was hoping someone would have an idea of how I can perform a calculation directly on a Pro Report without having to actually add the calculation to my attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

I would try calculating the fields outside of the Report interface and see the performance there. I'm not seeing much on field calculations in the ArcGIS Pro documentation, just this on summary stats: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/reports/calculate-summary-statistics-in-a-report.htm.